# How can I use a local network shared POS printer from a server in PHP?

Tags: php, networking, printing, yii2, point-of-sale

Is there a possibility to connect a locally shared [POS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_of_sale) printer from the PHP server.  While working on the PHP application in my own localhost, I am able to connect and print data to LAN shared printer. But it's not working in Production mode after moving it to the server. Are there possibilities or chances to connect a LAN-shared printer to a production PHP server?

Comment: Only if there's an open network connection between the printer and the server running PHP. If there isn't one, and you can't create one (either by firewall config, VPN, or whatever), then the answer is no. This is no different to connecting any computer / device to any other computer / device - you need an open network connection between them.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said before, if you want to print from a Web page to a printer on a server, you can write a print routine that runs on the server and wrap it in a web method, or Web API call.  This is a simple way of printing Web page text to a central printer.